# SQL: remove hashtag from end of the strings

Tags: sql, database

I have a database like this:

```
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| PosScore    | float       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| NegScore    | float       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| SynsetTerms | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

some of the SynsetTerms have # at the end.
Can I just use an SQL query and remove them?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It means there are some values like **fall#** and I want to change it just **fall**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an `update` statement:

```
update t
   set SynsetTerms = left(SynsetTerms, length(SynsetTerms) - 1)
   where SynsetTerms like '%#';
```

If you want to remove all occurrences of `'#'`:

```
update t
   set SynsetTerms = replace(SynsetTerms, '#', '')
   where SynsetTerms like '%#%';
```

Answer (score 1):

In your select or update statement just do this:

```
SELECT replace(synsetTerms, '#','') from table
```

or

```
UPDATE table set synsetTerms =  replace(synsetTerms, '#','')
```

if you just want to update the records that contain the '#' symbol you can add the following WHERE clause:

```
WHERE synsetTerms like '%#'
```